# DataFrame: add column with the size of a group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
    fsq digits  digits_type
0    1   1       odd
1    2   1       odd
2    3   1       odd
3    11  2       even
4    22  2       even
5    101 3       odd
6    111 3       odd
```

and I want to add a last column, *count*, containing the number of *fsq* belonging to the *digits* group, i.e:

```
    fsq digits  digits_type   count
0    1   1       odd          3
1    2   1       odd          3
2    3   1       odd          3
3    11  2       even         2
4    22  2       even         2
5    101 3       odd          2
6    111 3       odd          2
```

Since there are 3 *fsq* rows that has *digits* equal to 1, 2 *fsq* rows that has *digits* equal to 2, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
In [395]: df['count'] = df.groupby('digits')['fsq'].transform(len)

In [396]: df
Out[396]: 
   fsq  digits digits_type  count
0    1       1         odd      3
1    2       1         odd      3
2    3       1         odd      3
3   11       2        even      2
4   22       2        even      2
5  101       3         odd      2
6  111       3         odd      2

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: small question: how do you paste iPython input/output into the Stackoverflow code format?

Comment: Thanks DSM.

I just copied from the terminal, pasted here. Then select the text and hit CTRL-k to format it as code.

Answer (score 8):

In general, you should use Pandas-defined methods, where possible. This will often be more efficient.

In this case you can use `'size'`, in the same vein as `df.groupby('digits')['fsq'].size()`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit df.groupby('digits')['fsq'].transform('size')  # 3.44 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('digits')['fsq'].transform(len)     # 11.6 ms per loop
```